# Receiving 'data' of `$http.post('/someUrl', data).success` at server

Tags: http, angularjs, express, http-post

$http.post in Angularjs:-

```
$http({method: 'Post', url: '/signUp'} , {greeting: 'hi'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
    alert(data);
  });
```

Node- Express.js Server

```
app.post('/signUp', function (req, res){
    res.send(req.body.greeting);
});
```

The angular code works fine. How do I receive {greeting: 'hi'} at the server?
`req.body.greeting` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine if you change     `{method: 'Post', url: '/signUp'} , {greeting: 'hi'}` to

```
$http({method: 'Post', url: '/signUp', data: {greeting: 'hi'}}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
    alert(data);
  });
```

Comment: yup. Finally after all your edits. this one works! :) Gracias